# Are there differences in the binary between an app downloaded from the Apple App Store versus loaded from XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have a very strange problem. I have an App that works perfectly when tested on the simulator, or devices that I manually load the app onto by plugging them into XCode [version 10.1]. I also use this website called Diawi which is a tool for developers to deploy Development and In-house applications directly to the devices.

As far as I can tell, it works in all circumstances EXCEPT when the app is downloaded from the Apple App Store.

However, regardless of what user account or data I'm using, the App Store version invariably fails with:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException

[MyObject MyMethod]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2813243f0
```

I have tried everything to reproduce this problem locally to no avail. I have created brand new user accounts, cleaned out my iOS test Device, reinstalled the app via XCode, ensured both the app-store and x-code launched version of my App are connecting to the same exact web service, made certain both versions are running the same source code, etc.

I would have expected my simulated / ad-hoc testing version of the app to work the same as the App Store version.

Are there any optimization tricks or behind the scene changes being made that would cause this kind of discrepancy?

Comment: Do you have multiple targets ? If yes, it may happen because some files / frameworks are not linked to the AppStore target. It may also be caused by different iOS versions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my 'Debug' build configuration was including extra code that the 'Release' build configuration wasn't.

I was able to debug by going to Edit Scheme and changing the build configuration to Release, from there the compiler was able to tell me what went wrong.